# Bad way of creating multiple nodes? Runs slow with lots of memory consumption

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to create a simple set of relationships/nodes where a club is LOCATED in a region which is PART_OF a location which BELONGS_TO a country. The scrip below with 150 lines (shown only 2) executes for a minute and creates 150 nodes, 150 labels,150 relationships.

```
merge (c:COUNTRY {name:'Fictus'})           

merge(d1:club {name:'alpha'})   
merge(l1:LOCATION {name:'shore'})   
merge(r1:REGION {name:'north park'})    
merge d1-[:LOCATED]->l1 
merge l1-[:BELONGS_TO]->r1 
merge r1-[:IS_PART_OF]->c

merge(d2:club {name:'beta'})    
merge(l2:LOCATION {name:'shore'})   
merge (r2:REGION {name:'north park'})   
merge d2-[:LOCATED]->l2 
merge l2-[:BELONGS_TO]->r2 
merge r2-[:IS_PART_OF]->c
```

two questions:
1. Isn't it supposed to create only 3 labels? Why it says 150?
2. Evidently it's a bad way to create the objects. What is the right one via a script?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question has identical Cypher queries (except for the variable names) for the 2 shown "lines". Is this a typo, or are all 150 lines really identical?

Comment: typo. corrected. essentially it's a start-like structure where ever next layer has 2-3 child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, there should only be 3 node labels. I believe the reported creation of "150 labels" is misleading -- it is probably just telling you that 150 nodes had been *assigned* a label.

If you are truly trying to start a new database, then you can use the REST API to [perform batch operations](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-execute-multiple-operations-in-batch-streaming).